# How to group a list by multiple fields in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have a list -

```
List<Student> students // contains student data already

public class Student{
    // contains
    String name;
    Address address;
    int age;
    int avgGrade;
}
```

Now I want to group `List<Student>` students into `List<List<Student>> stds` where for any `i`, if we do `stds.get(i)`, we should be able to observe that all the students in that list should have the same `age` and `avgGrade`.

Is there a better way other than manually creating a list, iterating over each student from the initial list (after sorting) and adding them to the new list as required?

I was hoping something like streams would help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a tuple class with `age` and `avgGrade` fields that you can fill from a student, then put them in a `Map<AgeGrade, List<Student>>`.

Comment: You'll be doing equivalently the same anyhow. Start with what works, then improve it. You shouldn't need a pre-sort if you're putting them into containers where they're "equal".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need sorting, you need to group (the answer is literally in the question).  To do the grouping by multiple fields use custom class:

```
public class Key {

  private final int age;
  private final int avg;

  //constructor

  //getters, if needed

  //equals and hashCode overrides!!!
}
```

If you are using java 16+, use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) instead:

```
public record Key(int age, int avg) {
}
```

The grouping can be easily done with a [groupingBy collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a Collector implementing a "group by" operation on input elements of type T, grouping elements according to a classification function, and returning the results in a Map.

Then just get the values of the map and transform to list (if needed):

```
public class SoMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> list = List.of(new Student("I", 11, 5), new Student("C", 11, 4), new Student("D", 11, 5));
    List<List<Student>> grouped = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> new Key(student.getAge(), student.getAvgGrade())))
            .values() //values is Collection<List<Student>>
            .stream()
            .toList();
    System.out.println(grouped);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could make good use of `record` for Key, then you won't need to manually create equals and hashCode.

Comment: @k314159 Thanks, I don't know why I didnt think of a record when I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use a stream for this with [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)). Since your example has int two ints you can just create a string from the values. That will create a unique key for every integer combination.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> graded = students.stream().collect( 
        Collectors.groupingBy( 
            s ->{ return s.age + "," + s.aveGrade;}
        )
    );
```

In this example I generated the key by combining the two integers as a string.

A more extensible approach would be to use List that way each object will be checked.

```
Map<List<?>, List<Student>> graded = students.stream().collect( 
            Collectors.groupingBy( 
                s ->List.of(s.age, s.ave)
            )
        );
```

Then you can decide which elements you want to use and it doesn't depend on unique string representations.

Comment: This answer is so easy to implement and most importantly worked like a charm for my case. Thanks mate!